# How to glue 1 image on top of another and keeping them together after resizing with max-width:100%

Tags: css

I have width: 100% which is very necessary for me. Based on this example code, can someone help me to glue the orange symbol on top of any key and keeping it there even if I resize the browser? like how its happening with the keyboard already.... Thank you so much!

**DEMO**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<hsrc="https://i.imgur.com/jc1rbcJ.gif">
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.imageOne {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.
```

Comment: Don't use pixel values, use percentages to position the overlay.

Comment: but what if you need to make all keys, its % the same precise?

Comment: They won't be...they'll all be different places on the image - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha

Comment: You can use floating values for % too, if you need to be precise (example `top: 16.6667%;`)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fnwujLsq/

Comment: Hi Paulie!, I'm trying to adapt your example but I got one last problem, I would like to have the key at 100% of its own size, instead your pin that is bigger and you shrieked, how can I do if I have a specific resolution of the keyboard and key to match each other? here is the progress made with your code, thank you so much. https://jsfiddle.net/rihotzu/jvfkrbeh/1/

Comment: Hi, Pauli, how can you make the Y icon shrink together at the same time with the keyboard when resizing? https://jsfiddle.net/fnwujLsq/

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 600px; max-width: 100%;
width: 100%; max-width: 600px;
```

Parent is 1000px wide
Width says element should be 600px wide. That doesn't break the max-width rule, so 600px it is!
Width says element should be 1000px wide. That breaks max-width rule, so forces element down to 600px.
Parent is 320px wide
Width says element should be 600px wide. That breaks the max-width rule which says element can only be at most 320px wide, so 320px it is!
Width says element should be 320px wide. That doesn't break the max-width rule, so 320px it is!

find more on https://css-tricks.com/tale-width-max-width/

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out each screen has different sizes. So there are two key factors in your request you need to take care off. The position and the size of your `.imageTwo` need to be always in %, only then it will have the same position and size of its parent `.container`. For your suggested letter Y on the keyboard I would do this:

```
.imageTwo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 33.5%;
  width: 2%;
  height: 5%;
}
```